# How to store forecasted values with predict() function

Tags: r

I have a time series populated with 2 years of observed data points and am using Holt-Winters to create a forecast model. I then use the R predict function to extrapolate 24 months into the future.

The current predict object is a time series and looks like:

```
      Jan  Feb  Mar June ...
2012  xxx  yyy  zzz xxy
2013  xyx  yxy  zyz zxz
```

However, when I access the TS object such as myPrediction[1], I am only returned the value xxx.

I am trying to store both the DATE and VALUE of the predicted object. Ultimately, I am looking to create a data.frame or some object where I can directly export to a MySQL table that shows:

```
Projection Date  Value
2012-01-01        xxx
2012-02-01        yyy
2012-03-01        zzz
...
...
2013-01-01        xyx
```

Are there any easy ways to create two columns that show the Date + Value of my returned predict function?

Answer (score 0):

Time series objects are a bit weird. They are vectors that store their starting and ending times as fractional years and the number of intervals in attributes, rather than being accessible as columns or as rownames. You could construct a dataframe with the two columns as :

```
 tsobj <- ts(1:24,  frequency = 12, start = c(2012, 1))
 tsattr <- tsp(tsobj)
 data.frame(Dates =seq(tsattr[1], tsattr[2], by= 1/tsattr[3] ),
            Value = tsobj )
          Dates Value
1  2012.000     1
2  2012.083     2
3  2012.167     3
4  2012.250     4
5  2012.333     5
 snip
#------a character valued column ----------
data.frame(Dates =paste( rep( c(2012,2013), each= 12 ),seq(1:12 ), sep="-"), 
            Value = tsobj)
     Dates Value
1   2012-1     1
2   2012-2     2
3   2012-3     3
4   2012-4     4
5   2012-5     5
snip
#------Date-classed column -----
 data.frame(Dates =as.Date(paste( rep( c(trunc(tsattr[1]), trunc(tsattr[2]) ), 
                            each= 12 ),
                            seq(1:12 ),
                            1,
                            sep="-")), 
             Value = tsobj)
#----
        Dates Value
1  2012-01-01     1
2  2012-02-01     2
3  2012-03-01     3
4  2012-04-01     4
5  2012-05-01     5
6  2012-06-01     6
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have the Dates column in some sort of DATE format? such as yyyy-mm? Not sure if this is possible since I cannot think of how to find out how to pull which month the first element of the TS starts on (it's not january every time)

For example if I ran my predict function in February 2013, the first element would be:

`2012
March  xxx `

Comment: You probably need to post a reproducible example of an edge case. My simple example poses no difficulties that I can see.